# libgdx check actor = stage.hit(..) as null

Tags: null, libgdx, actor, stage

I am facing a problem while checking the stage.hit(..) as actor or null

```
Actor actor = stage.hit(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, true);
if(null != actor){
// something
}
```

here after debugging i come to know that actor is getting null
but still control is going into the if loop

is something wrong in the above code ??

thanks

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you posted. The problem could be else where, do you have a more complete code example of your problem?

Comment: i solved this problem like this :
`code` if(null==actor){
  // do something 
}else{
     // do something..
}